# fopen fails with GetLastError()=0 - why is that?

Tags: c++, fopen

i have a loaded environment with lots of threads opening the same file for reading.
the problem is - i get null when i fopen, but the errno is 0.

How is that even possible?

Code:

```
 if ((fParm = fopen(FullFileName.c_str(), "r")) == NULL)
  {
      printf("%d", GetLastError());
  }
```

As pointed in MSDN - after fopen fails - you should check errno. and that's what we do:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

(ignore the printf, it's not used in the original code - i wrote it only to simplify the question).

Thanks for your help.

---------------------- EDIT --------------------------

i actually used GetLastError() instead of good ol' errno - which caused the error to show 0.

Comment: fopen - it's a very old legacy code. 
i'm not using printf, we write it to a log file - and i used it here only for simplify the question

Comment: But the `c_str` bit is not! Surely if it is legacy it use to work

Comment: @EdHeal - the full file name is a custom class we use, it points to the correct char* - but that's not my issue, i want to focus on why this behavior occurs

Comment: @ArielB It's possible that the code that writes to a log file zeroes errno, causing you to log the wrong value. Can you paste the actual code you are using or 100% confirm that you can replicate the problem with the code you pasted?

Comment: Are you sure that it is safe to use errno in a multithreaded application ? As it is global, it should be shared between all threads ... Could you open (n times) the file before starting your threads, each with its FILE ?

Comment: Did you `#include <errno.h>`; since `errno` is often a macro. BTW, you should use `perror` or `strerror(errno)` instead!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i confirm that there's no change that we do (as i managed in my private environment to see that it actually returns 2 (if im not mistaken) if the file doesnt exist.

i can't open the file n times as n is unknown and the file is open upon request. and as i understand it's safe. 

i do have a feeling that it fails to open because too many handles are opened maybe? (although we close all handles). but i would expect to see a correct error code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i actually use "GetLastError()" to get the errno

Comment: `GetLastError` is not in the C99 (or other) standard.

Comment: @ArielB `GetLastError` doesn't return `errno`, at least not on any platform I know of.

Comment: BTW, your `printf` should have a format string ending with `\n`  and/or you should call `fflush`

Comment: but the documentation refers that this is the way we should check the error after fopen - i still dont understand why its 0

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes i know about the printf, it's not in my code - i just added it to simplify.

Comment: @ArielB What platform is this? Can you provide a link to the documentation? This is totally non-standard behavior and isn't the case on any platform I know of.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Windows 2008R2

"Always check the return value to see whether the pointer is NULL before you perform any further operations on the file. If an error occurs, the global variable errno is set and may be used to get specific error information. For more information, see errno, _doserrno, _sys_errlist, and _sys_nerr."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is Windows and you are using `GetLastError`, your code will not work. The documentation is clear:

> Each of these functions [`fopen` and `_wfopen`] returns a pointer to the open file. A null pointer value indicates an error. If filename or mode is NULL or an empty string, these functions trigger the invalid parameter handler, which is described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, these functions return NULL **and set errno** to EINVAL. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) (emphasis added)

As on other platforms, `fopen` returns an error by setting `errno`. You should not be calling `GetLastError`, but logging the value of `errno`. They are two completely different things.

Calling `GetLastError` may work by accident in some cases. If the underlying cause of the error is an error from another function in the Windows API (like `CreateFile`), that other function may happen to call `SetLastError`, and it's quite possible no other code in `fopen` will change that value, so it may sometimes happen to hold the correct error. But if the error comes from `fopen` itself, `GetLastError` won't give the right information.

Comment: uhm, so how do i get the last error? what sohuld i print?

Comment: @ArielB Are you 100% sure you are checking `errno`, not calling `GetLastError`?

Comment: no, i'm calling GetLastError, but it's only our implementation for errno
#define GetLastError()  errno

Comment: In his case, neither the filename nor the mode are null pointers, so he shouldn't get `EINVAL`.  (I get `ENOENT` if the file doesn't exist, which is 2.)

Comment: @ArielB If you've done a `#define` on `errno`, you have undefined behavior, and all bets are off.  It's highly likely that `fopen` calls `GetLastError()` itself, in order to set `errno`, and that it then calls `SetLastError()` to clear it.

Comment: @ArielB It sounds like your code is really, really broken. The only reason I can imagine to do the `#define` you describe above is for Windows compatibility (otherwise, *why* call it `GetLastError` of all possible choices and deliberately cause confusion due to the Windows function of the same name) -- but calling `GetLastError` after `fopen` won't work on Windows. So wtf?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz
David and James, we define the GetLastError as a static method in our own class, so we use    CompanyClass::GetLastError().

delete all what i said, and note the code i entered above - we only print out the "errno". that's all.
the errno is 0 while no null is being sent (The path is correct).

if we reduce the number of threads in the system - the error is not reproduced.

So no - we don't call the system function "GetLastError", we actually just print out the good ol' "errno"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you were right, i was mistaken and did log the GetLastError which apparently was the system call.
i switched it to errno into a variable and it showed the correct error.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not guarantee that `errno` will be set to a meaningful value although POSIX defines that it will return NULL in case of failure and set errno, [IEEE Std 1003.1-2013](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html).

So depending of the implementation used in the libraries linked and the set of standards which has been implemented you might see different results.

You mentioned in the comments that you used `GetLastError()` on Windows which is supposed to be [thread-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx). Unfortunately, you did not edit the main question to reflect all these facts which are scattered in the comments.

Comment: implementation, specifically library, not compiler.

Comment: POSIX refers to unix type OS? we use windows.. and i dont think its relevant

Comment: Maybe you can specify more details about your environment so we can check ?

Comment: @ArielB: It is only mentioned as an example for an implementation using licence to set `errno`. So it is relevant. And if you only want windows-answers, you should really have said so (It's not quite too late, clarify your question with the details).

Comment: No, it could also be the compiler itself (not only the library). The standard does not prohibit `errno` being a macro expanded to some implementation-specific compiler builtin.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `errno` can expand to a compiler-intrinsic, yes. But it's still the library which does or does not set it.

Comment: The C standard doesn't specify what happens to `errno` when `fopen` returns a null pointer, but the intent is clear, and MSC sets it in case of error too.

Comment: `as the value may have been changed by printf` Why? both first and second code are equal; Whether you pass `errno` directly or not, argument is evaluated *before* function is called.

Comment: @JamesKanze so how do i get the error that caused the fopen to fail? or i misunderstood you.

in my tests - when printing out "errno" it gives the correct value.
only in a heavy multithreaded environment - it starts to behave weird

Comment: I saw this note about POSIX and thread safety http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html, but it may or may not be relevant to you, we cannot know because your question lacks information to reproduce the issue. GetLastError() is supposed to be thread safe.

Comment: @ArielB The C standard requires `errno` to be thread local.  Whether MSC is conformant here or not, however, I don't know.  But if there is a problem in the library, about the only solution is to not use the parts of the library which are problematic.  Which in this case might mean `fopen`.

Answer (score 0):

We have to guess because you haven't shown us your real code. But one possibility: your real code does something like this:

```
 if ((fParm = fopen(FullFileName.c_str(), "r")) == NULL)
 {
      SomeLogMacro(Severity, "%d", errno);
 }
```

That macro expands to something like this:

```
 if ((fParm = fopen(FullFileName.c_str(), "r")) == NULL)
 {
      do { if (ShouldLog(Severity)) DoLog("%d", errno); } while (false);
 }
```

If the `ShouldLog` function changes the value of `errno`, you will log the wrong value.

Comment: i understand what you said
this is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [MSDN documentation for fopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) I see that it doesn't set the lasterror (it just returns 0 on failure). Reading the [MSDN documentation for GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I see that it returns just, well, the last error ever set by anybody (not fopen).

Comment: More precisely, `GetLastError` returns the results of the last call to `SetLastError`.  `fopen` certainly calls something like `CreateFile`, which would call `SetLastError` if it failed, but what happens in `fopen` after that is anybody's guess.  My guess would be that it maps the results of `GetLastError` to `errno`, and clears `GetLastError`.  (At least, that's how I would implement it.)

Comment: Forget the "GetLastError", we created our own GetLastERror - we just print out the errno.

Answer (score 0):

Edit David Schwartz was right : the problem is that fopen does not call `GetLastError` - see below

Ok, I saw in comments to other answers that you have a `#define GetLastError() errno`. You should have stated that in initial question, because `errno` is required to be thread safe by Posix, but I'm not sure that it is on Windows, when I see that warning in MSDN about global variables (including `errno`) :

> These global variables have been deprecated for the more secure functional versions, which should be used in place of the global variable

But `GetLastError` **is** thread safe, simply Microsoft says :

> You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data. That is because some functions call SetLastError with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code set by the most recently failed function.

So the only foolproof way is to have a **local** variable, say `lastError` and do :

```
if ((fParm = fopen(FullFileName.c_str(), "r")) == NULL)
  {
      int lastError = errno; // in reality calls GetLastError immediately and saves it current value even if other functions later calls SetLastError(0)
      printf("%d", lastError);
  }
```

EDIT :

In fact, `fopen` does not call `SetLastError` by itself. Here is an demo of the problem :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fd = fopen("", "r");
    int lastErr = GetLastError();
    int err = errno;

    printf("errno : %d - GetLastError %d\n", err, lastErr);
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is :

```
errno : 22 - GetLastError 0
```

In fact what is to blame is `#define GetLastError() errno`. But in a multi-threaded application, I really urge you to copy immediately `errno` into a local variable.

Comment: can you explain?
what is the different to put the errno in a local variable? i'm sending it to a log function so it should be copied anyway "by value"

Comment: @ArielB Oups, I got it : David Schwartz was right : the problem is that fopen does not call `GetLastError`. I've edited my post ...